# Magento: How to add multiple quantity through custom option?

Tags: magento

I have to add the multiple qty option for the product detail page. I have manage to get the qty into custom option. but got setting how use that qty. I want to do this with simple product.

Image for complete scenario::

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using Advanced Custom Options by Mageworx.